# Android - one singleton common activity/screens in application

Tags: android, service, android-activity, singleton, screens

In Android application, I have one request that aims to use one common Activity/screen in many screens or in overall of the application.

For example:

- **Screen A** contains **screen common C** (to get better sense, it contains of list of items)
  ==> during the working on **A**, **C** might be modified to have add/modify/remove any items.
- Now to to **Screen B** and in turn it contains **screen C** also.
  ==> request: **C** must be the same as one in **A** and the data is obviously the same.

One more request: it doesn't need to store the list items of **C** in the DB or in the preference since I thought the loading data phase can reduce the smoothly of the **screen B** or **A** at the first time. 
How's your opinion about this thinking?

Anybody has some ideas about this situation? I'm really appreciate so much.

Thanks,
Tri.

Answer (score 0):

Screens or Activities in Android are independent. You can't nest Activities. I could think of two solutions :
a) Save your data as an array List and pass it to B from A when B opens. Since it seems both contain a common layout as part of their own layout, include that layout using `<include layout.`  in your xml for both A and B layouts. 
b) If you plan to use fragments, make C a fragment and use it in two activites A and B ( could go for better design approaches though when using fragments)

Comment: yeah, for the nested Activity, I didn't think likes that :) maybe my sentence makes confusing. For the common screen, do you think that we just need a singleton view in overall application. So that when going to Screen B, we just get that instance to embed without re-building again (so we don't need to store list item anymore)?

Comment: from what I get, you can manage things with a single activity, and make views visible/invisble on your need. It would be better than going to a new activity altogether.